# L'usage du verbe « survoler »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

**Je me demande si l'on peut utiliser le verbe *survoler* dans un sens figuratif comme « inspecter ».**

Par exemple :

> Pour comprendre cette idée, il faut **survoler** l'histoire de cette idée.

C'est-à-dire, il faut inspecter l'histoire de l'idée.

En anglais, je dirais "to survey the history" ou "to look over the history".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cet usage est parfaitement légitime, mais je note que "survoler" implique un **examen relativement superficiel et rapide**, du genre que l'on ferait dans l'introduction d'un article scientifique. Si l'on fait un *survey* plus détaillé, *examiner* est un verbe plus approprié.

On n'emploie pas *inspecter* dans ce sens, puisque ce verbe signifie plutôt "examiner pour vérifier l'absence de défauts ou problèmes".

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui est légitime ? C'est plus qu'une nuance de sens, c'est presque un contre-sens. Comme *soigner un travail* et *bacler un travail* sont deux expressions signifiant que l'on a fait un travail mais ont un sens totalement opposé, ici *survoler* et *examiner* sont également en opposition, même si leur base commune est en effet *considérer / s'intéresser à / regarder*.

Comment: On pourrait imaginer cette variante de question si celle-ci ne te choque pas : « Je me demande si l'on peut utiliser le verbe enguirlander dans un sens figuratif comme 'complimenter' ». Gênant, non ?

Answer (score 1):

survoler, verbe transitif
Sens 1 Voler au dessus. Synonyme voler Anglais to fly over
Sens 2 Parcourir, examiner de façon superficielle.

il faut inspecter l'histoire de l'idée.
En anglais:It is necessary to inspect the history of the idea.

Comment: J'ai trouvé quelque chose similaire sur WordReference, mais je suis sceptique.  Votre source ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Oui, on peut effectivement utiliser *survoler* au sens figuratif.

Cela signifie non pas survoler physiquement, au sens littéral, comme d'autres l'ont rappelé, mais **parcourir avec un certain détachement et dans sa globalité** un domaine, une oeuvre ou tout autre sujet d'attention.

Cependant, attention !

2) Cela ne signifie *pas du tout* examiner ou inspecter, verbes qui impliquent *au contraire* **une analyse rigoureuse**, un souci du détail.